# How can I attach an event when a certain class is added/removed to any tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's suppose I have a css class named "foo".

I would like to have two event handlers:
- the first event handler would be triggered when "foo" is added as a class to any tag
- the second event handler would be triggered when "foo" is removed as a class from any tag

How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no cross-browser event to do that.

If the class is always added/removed by *your* code, just write a wrapper function to do it and then use that rather than `.addClass` / `.removeClass`.

Alternately (and I'm not actively suggesting this), you could wrap `.addClass` and `.removeClass`:

```
var realAddClass = jQuery.fn.addClass;
jQuery.fn.addClass = function() {
    // Fire some event here
    return realAddClass.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

...but that's *really* intrusive.

Both of those last suggestions do, of course, assume that the only way the class is added/removed is via jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

[**This jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/HGrSG/) shows how I'd go about it

```
    // create a list of classes that you want to handle add and/or remove actions
    var classesThatIWantToFireAnEventFor = [
        {class: 'foo', add: false, remove: true },
        {class: 'bar', add: true, remove: true }
    ];

    // create the event handlers for each scenario
    var HandlesClassRemoved = function() {
        // implementation goes here
         alert('Running custom "removeClass" handler for css class .foo');
    };

    // create the event handlers for each scenario
    var HandlesClassAdded = function() {
        // implementation goes here
             alert('Running custom "addClass" handler for css class .foo');
    };

    var originalAddClass = jQuery.fn.addClass;
    var originalRemoveClass = jQuery.fn.removeClass;

    // override jquery's add class
    jQuery.fn.addClass = function(){
        // Execute the original method.
        originalAddClass.apply(this, arguments);

        // check in the arguments if the class you want to handle 'add' is added
        for(var i=0;i<=arguments.length;i++) {
            var c = arguments[i];
            $(classesThatIWantToFireAnEventFor).each(function() {
                if((this.class === c) && (this.add)) {
                // if it is and your list has a 'add' flag, call the handler method
                    HandlesClassAdded();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    // override jquery's add class
    jQuery.fn.removeClass = function(){
        // Execute the original method.
        originalRemoveClass.apply(this, arguments);

        // check in the arguments if the class you want to handle 'add' is added
        for(var i=0;i<=arguments.length;i++) {
            var c = arguments[i];
            $(classesThatIWantToFireAnEventFor).each(function() {
                if((this.class === c) && (this.remove)) {
                // if it is and your list has a 'add' flag, call the handler method
                    HandlesClassRemoved();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    ​
```

[**Check it out at jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/HGrSG/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need delegate event handler to those tags, because toggling class `.foo` over any item will treated as dynamic element.

```
$('#parent').on('click', '.foo', function() {
  alert('class is foo');
});

$('#parent').on('mouseover', ':not(.foo)', function() {
  alert('class is foo');
});
```

Here `#parent` is a selector that contains the element `.foo` or element not without `.foo`. You may have something other container and need to change them.

Here. `:not(.foo)` will be applied for all element without class `.foo`, so it is better to use some other `class` to those element.